# java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET from PhoneGap's FileTransfer

Tags: android, cordova, socketexception

The program throws an exception when executing the following function:

```
    testDownloadFunc: function() {
    console.log("testDownload");
    var remoteFile = "http://192.168.55.177/MvcApplication6/Download/getFile";
    var localFileName = "Test01.properties";

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
            var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
            if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
                localPath = localPath.substring(7);
            }
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.download(remoteFile,
                localPath, function(entry) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                }, fail);
        }, fail);
    }, fail);       
}
```

> The following exception has been thrown: 02-01 16:01:16.920:
>   E/FileTransfer(23147):
>   {"target":"/storage/sdcard0/Test01.properties","source":"http://192.168.55.177/MvcApplication6/Download/getFile","http_status":200,"code":3} 02-01 16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147): java.net.SocketException:
>   recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) 02-01
>   16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):  at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552) 02-01
>   16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):  at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516) 02-01 16:01:16.920:
>   E/FileTransfer(23147):    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488) 02-01
>   16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46) 02-01
>   16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
>   02-01 16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:304) 02-01
>   16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):  at
>   libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:52)
>   02-01 16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):    at
>   java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163) 02-01 16:01:16.920:
>   E/FileTransfer(23147):    at
>   org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.download(FileTransfer.java:507) 02-01
>   16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:88) 02-01
>   16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:231)
>   02-01 16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 02-01 16:01:16.920:
>   E/FileTransfer(23147): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom
>   failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) 02-01 16:01:16.920:
>   E/FileTransfer(23147):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native
>   Method) 02-01 16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):    at
>   libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131) 02-01 16:01:16.920:
>   E/FileTransfer(23147):    at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164) 02-01
>   16:01:16.920: E/FileTransfer(23147):  at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513) 02-01 16:01:16.920:
>   E/FileTransfer(23147):    ... 10 more

What is the root cause of the problem and how to solve it?
I use PhoneGap 2.1 and Android 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but this problem is somewhere in java IO core, while reading too many **lines** of text, and I solved this by reducing the number of lines of my JSON code from 450 to 10 lines.

I figured out this solution cause I did the same job using java and encountered same problem while it reaches the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method.

And also it may helps to read files in another way, such as read them using byteBuffer or something. But in your case (Phone gap), I've no IDEA :D